# XBMC: Connecting to a SMB shared file with MAC address

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I've got a SMB shared folder on my Windows notebook and I connect to it via IP address in RaspBMC, I had the IP static until I realised that if I went out of the network I had to set it back to dynamic.

Is there any way of accessing a SMB shared folder from RaspBMC using the MAC address instead of the IP?

Comment: And what is wrong with DNS Names? MAC addresses are very low level and not really recommended to do that. MAC's are best used in firewalls and traffic shaping. So you would need to setup IPTables and query IPTables for the MAC to get the IP. But if you setup your Pi to a non clashing DNS name like `raspberrypi1`, use DHCP and the DNS on your router, you can just connect to SMB by typing `//raspberrypi1`

Answer (score 1):

It's more simple to just use windows network zones so it automatically uses a static IP for only your router, or give your computer a [WINS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service) name and get kodi to use the name not the IP.

```
grep smb /home/osmc/.kodi/userdata/sources.xml
<path pathversion="1">smb://WINNAME/Video/</path>
```

But yes you can write a root script to connect by mac address:

```
IP=$(nmap -p 445 192.168.0.0/24 | grep -B 4 B8:27:EB:9E:87:2A | grep "report for" | perl -pe 's/.* //g')
sed 's/(smb:\/\/)[^\/]+(\/)/$1'$IP'$2/' /home/osmc/.kodi/userdata/sources.xml
```

Then have it run from [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) or on command from the [Kodi Advanced Launcher](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Advanced_Launcher)

Setting up a DNS server is another option but more complicated.